# Error insert data in mysql from form

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Please tell me what my mistake is. I write a guest book. Created a database. in phpmyadmin she appeared. Next, I created a form and an ajax script that sends the data. The message when sending alert writes that the data is written to the database, but in fact the table is empty. What am I doing wrong?

Create DB

```
define ("HOST", "localhost");

define ("DATABASE", "guests_db");   

define ("MYSQL_USER", "alekspvn");  

define ("MYSQL_PASS", "123");  


function create_db () {
$connect_db=mysql_connect(HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASS)   
    or die("No connection with SQL");  
mysql_query ("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ".DATABASE)   
    or die ("Error create database");  
mysql_select_db(DATABASE)  
    or die("Error connection database");  
mysql_query ("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS book  
             (id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,  
              username VARCHAR (100),  
              email VARCHAR (100),
              message TEXT)")  
    or die ("Error creation table");
}
```

Script ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#submit').click(function() {
                var username = $('#username').val();
                var email = $('#email').val();
                var message = $('#message').val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    cache: false,        
                    url: 'index.php',
                    data: {username: username, email: email, message: message},
                    success: function(data) {
                        alert('data has been stored to database');
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

My form

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
<label>Name :</label>
<input id="username" type="text">
<label>Email :</label>
<input id="email" type="text">
<label>Password :</label>
<input id="message" type="text">
<input id="submit" type="button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP insert

```
 <?php
$connect_db=mysql_connect(HOST, MYSQL_USER, MYSQL_PASS)
    or die("No connection with SQL");  

mysql_select_db("javascript", $connect_db);


function insert_db () {
$username=$_POST['username'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$message=$_POST['message'];
    $query = "INSERT INTO `book` VALUES ('$username','$email','$message')";
    $resource = mysql_query($query) 
        or die (mysql_error());
}

?>
```

Comment: You're not calling the insert_db() function. Also in that same file your selecting `javascript` database not `guests_db`. also, the constants won't be set.

Comment: how about console.log(data) and you'll see a nice error

Comment: You where call this funtion ?? `insert_db ()` so how data is inserted